# Add a new column to a dataframe based on the values in other 2 columns (Pyspark required)

Tags: pyspark

[image]

I want to add a column named "joint_pred_x"(x=0,1,2) base on the two values in "nb_pred_x" and "svm_pred_x", add 0 if nb=1, svm=1; add 1 if nb=1, svm=0; add 2 if nb=0, svm=1; add 3 if nb=0, svm=0.
I think withcolumn could do the job but I'm confused with the conditional logic. The solution needed to be pyspark only, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `case` statement.

```
+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|nb_pred_0|nb_pred_1|nb_pred_2|svm_pred_0|svm_pred_1|svm_pred_2|
+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|0.0      |1.0      |0.0      |0.0       |1.0       |0.0       |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+


from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

for i in range(0, 3):
    
    index = str(i)
    
    df = df.withColumn('joint_pred_' + index, expr(f'''
            CASE 
                WHEN {p1}_pred_{index} == 1 and {p2}_pred_{index} == 1 THEN 0
                WHEN {p1}_pred_{index} == 1 and {p2}_pred_{index} == 0 THEN 1
                WHEN {p1}_pred_{index} == 0 and {p2}_pred_{index} == 1 THEN 2
                WHEN {p1}_pred_{index} == 0 and {p2}_pred_{index} == 0 THEN 3
            END
        '''))

df.show(10, False)

+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|nb_pred_0|nb_pred_1|nb_pred_2|svm_pred_0|svm_pred_1|svm_pred_2|joint_pred_0|joint_pred_1|joint_pred_2|
+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|0.0      |1.0      |0.0      |0.0       |1.0       |0.0       |3           |0           |3           |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank u so much, it has adrdressed my question perfectly